# Update Coordinates in Mapbox every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I want the Mapbox map to update with user location (coordinates) every 5 seconds. The following script that I wrote refresh the whole map every 5 seconds.

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = '<my mapbox tocken>';

var distanceCount = 1;

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successLocation, errorLocation, {
    enableHighAccuracy: true
})

function successLocation(position) {
    console.log(position);
    
    setupMap([position.coords.longitude, position.coords.latitude]);
    setTimeout(runUpdate, 5000)
}

function errorLocation() {
    setupMap([-2.24, 53.48])
}

function setupMap(center) {
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: "map",
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
        center: center,
        zoom: 15
    })
}

function runUpdate() {
    var options;
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successLocation, errorLocation, options);
    distanceCount = distanceCount + 1
    console.log(distanceCount);
}
```

However, I just want to refresh the user coordinates and not the whole map refresh.

I tried with `watchPosition` and it's not working.

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiaG9uZ2tvbmdiYm95IiwiYSI6ImNqaWwxZjNiZzAwaWwzbGs3dDF0eGZ6eGMifQ.A0jNwza6KatLrAMa6roEMQ';

var distanceCount = 1;

navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(successLocation, errorLocation, {
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
})

function successLocation(position) {
    console.log(position);
    
    setupMap([position.coords.longitude, position.coords.latitude]);
    setTimeout(setupMap([getRandomInRange(-180,180,3), getRandomInRange(-90,90,3)]), 5000)
}

function errorLocation() {
    setupMap([-2.24, 53.48])
}

function setupMap(center) {
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: "map",
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
        center: center,
        zoom: 15
    })
}

function runUpdate() {
    var options;
    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(successLocation, errorLocation, options);
    distanceCount = distanceCount + 1
    console.log(distanceCount);
}

function getRandomInRange(from, to, fixed) {
    return (Math.random() * (to - from) + from).toFixed(fixed) * 1;
    // .toFixed() returns string, so ' * 1' is a trick to convert to number
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not be working because you are using `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`.

- `setTimeout` is "wait X amount of time and do".
- `setInterval` is "wait X amount of time and do, repeat every X amount of time".